# Screen density confusion

Tags: android, android-layout, android-drawable, android-screen-support

Let me start of by telling the research I have done.

On [developer.android.com](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) it states that the following should be done to support different screen sizes:

> - `res/layout/my_layout.xml              // layout for normal screen size ("default")`
> - `res/layout-large/my_layout.xml        // layout for large screen size`
> - `res/layout-xlarge/my_layout.xml       // layout for extra-large screen size`
> - `res/layout-xlarge-land/my_layout.xml  // layout for extra-large in landscape orientation`

It also states the drawables should be scaled like this:

> To create alternative bitmap drawables for different densities, you should follow the 3:4:6:8:12:16 scaling ratio between the six generalized densities. For example, if you have a bitmap drawable that's 48x48 pixels for medium-density screens, all the different sizes should be:
>
> - 36x36 (0.75x) for low-density
> - 48x48 (1.0x baseline) for medium-density
> - 72x72 (1.5x) for high-density
> - 96x96 (2.0x) for extra-high-density
> - 144x144 (3.0x) for extra-extra-high-density
> - 192x192 (4.0x) for extra-extra-extra-high-density

Now here is my question, lets say hypothetically I'm designing for nexus 10, in landscape mode. This device will then fall under `res/layout-large-land/` and its screen density will be under `(2.0x) for extra-high-density - xhdpi`.

But What I don't understand is that the nexus 10 has a tablet size screen but it falls under the xhdpi, meaning that the image that will be fetched from the drawable resource folder will be displayed smaller on this device. I have tested this on the nexus 10 and on my phone and the image is a lot smaller on the nexus 10, as I was expecting it would be.

I have been confused about this for some time now and I have done a lot of research. Can anybody please help me clarify this ones and for all. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The Nexus 10 sure has tablet size screen (10.1 in), but falls under the `xhdpi`(extra high density) class because of its `Pixel Per inch(ppi)` which is only 299. You can easily identify which class a device would fall into by checking it's DPI. Below is the density for different classes.

- `ldpi` - 120 dpi
- `mdpi` - 160 dpi
- `hdpi` - 240 dpi
- `xhdpi` - 320 dpi
- `xxhdpi` - 480 dpi

In that context, the PPI of the Samsung Galaxy Tab 10 inch tablet which also has a tablet size screen is only 149. Hence, it falls under the `mdpi` class. Refer to [this site](http://dpi.lv/), which helps to easily understand which device has what dpi and its density class. [This website](https://material.io/devices/) is also recommended to learn more about different device screen sizes.

Just an added information,  the Nexus 10 tablet is an `xhdpi` device, but uses `xxhdpi` class for it's launcher icons(arguably the most important part of an app).

Comment: If the answers solve the issue, please accept it by clicking the tick icon next to the answer for reference to future users.